# How to draw multiple vectors with different color?

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I want to draw lines using gnuplot.
data file is:

```
#X1 y1 x2 y2 colorNumber
123 567 798 900 1
788 900 87  89 2
....
```

I create a palette

```
set palette model RGB defined ( 1 'violet', 2 'red', 3 'blue', 4 'yellow', 5 'green', 6 'orange', 7 'cyan')
```

How can I draw each line with its color?

I try followng but it didn't work fine.

```
plot '~/Desktop/pointcolor.txt' using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2):3 with vectors palette nohead notitle
```

here is the result, the problem is line color didn't match with what I have deffined.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You data file contains a total of five columns, the fifth one contains your desired color numbers. So you need

```
plot '~/Desktop/pointcolor.txt' using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2):5 with vectors palette nohead notitle
```