# 3D vector field, 3rd dimension as color

Tags: gnuplot

So I'm trying to make a plot of three dimensional spins.I'd like to plot at coordinates `(x,y)` a vector of `length(dx,dy)`.

The trick is I want the `z-component` to be represented by the color of the arrow. This I am having difficulty figuring out how to do. Perhaps a vector field isn't the best choice?

Any help or suggestions are appreciated

Comment: That's a 2d field, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33700324/2604213 to get started. You only need some small changes

Comment: So the "color dimension" i'm trying to do is variable. I see that I can do x between a and b = some color, but is there a way to do something like a color map?

Comment: Yes, for color maps use `plot ... with image` or `splot ... with pm3d`. But I can't tell you which one you can use, and if you maybe also need `dgrid3d` because that depends on your actual data (gridded or not, file format etc).